# Rails link_to working wierd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have set up a link_to in a partial (update_dashboard) and it looks like this

```
link_to "Link", hash, {:url => {:controller => "results", :action => "update_report"}},     :remote => true
```

'hash' is a set of inputs that I am passing to the controller.

As it can be seen. i want the "Link" to map to the 'update_report' action in the 'results' controller.

but, i find that after the page is rendered, when I click on the link, it just displays the partial in a new page.

I went into Firebug and this is how the link is rendered

```
<a url="{:controller=>"results", :action=>"update_report"}" href="/test/update_dashboard?branch=xxxx&brand=xx&end_time=2012-02-29+22%3A59&repo=xxxx%2Fxx&start_time=2012-02-17+18%3A20">Link</a>
```

Why is the href pointing to /test/update_dashboard ? Why is is not taking the parameter that i supplied for the controller attribute

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at link_to method source at: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L236

Since 'hash' variable is a real hash with keys and values you need to merge it with url hash like this:

```
<% hash = { :param1 => "value1", :param2 => "value2"}  %>
<%= link_to 'MyLink', { :controller => "questions", :action => "index" }.merge(hash), :id => "link_id", :class => "link_class" %>
```

It produces the link you want:

```
<a href="/questions?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2" class="link_class" id="link_id">MyLink</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<%= link_to "Link", {
        :controller => "results", 
        :action => "update_report", 
        :hash => hash,
        :remote => true } %>
```

and if you are not using rails current version, try using

```
link_to_remote "link", :update => "results",
:url => { :controller => "results", :action => "update_report", :hash => hash }
```

[Reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote)

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. I am using Rails 3.1

Comment: This links to the correct controller and action but dosen't produce the link in the required format